# Как вызвать функцию MySQL в Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

```
 $command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT func(:name)")
                ->queryScalar([':name' => $name_f]);
```

Пытаюсь вызывать так, но выдаёт ошибку

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound
>   The SQL being executed was: SELECT func(:name FROM film)'

Где `func` - имя функции, `name` - поле в таблице БД, `name_f` - данные, записываемые в БД.

Сама функция:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS func;
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE FUNCTION func(nameFilm varchar(200)) 
RETURNS INT 
language sql
BEGIN
    declare countRow INT default 0;
    DECLARE idRow INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT count(*), id INTO countRow, idRow
    FROM `film`
    WHERE `name` LIKE nameFilm
    GROUP BY name;
    IF countRow > 0 THEN
        UPDATE `film` SET name = nameFilm WHERE id = idRow; 
    ELSE
        INSERT film (name) VALUES (nameFilm);
        SELECT id INTO idRow FROM film WHERE name LIKE nameFilm;
    END IF;
    RETURN idRow;
END$$;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#queryScalar()-detail) `queryScalar()` не принимает каких-либо аргументов.

Попробуйте сделать `bindParam()` или `bindValue()` (разница хорошо описана [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5077108/238336)):

```
$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT func(:name)")
            ->bindValue(':name', $name_f)
            ->queryScalar();
```